# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400> in junit

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mockito

it's my controller...

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Path("/categories")
    public POSResponse getAllCategories() {
        String countryCode="1";
        return infoService.getAllCategories(countryCode);
    }
```

it's my testController....

```
  @Mock
    InfoService infoService;
    @InjectMocks
    private InfoController infoController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(infoController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllCategoriesTest() throws Exception {
        POSResponse response=new POSResponse();
        Category category=new Category();
        category.setCountryCode(1);
        category.setDescription("Mother Dairy");
        response.setResponse(category);

        when(infoService.getAllCategories("1")).thenReturn(response);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/categories"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.description", is("Mother Dairy")));

        verify(infoService, times(1)).getAllCategories("1");
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(infoService);
    }
```

i am using jersey controller. 
when i call the method i got error msg"java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>"

Comment: in the controller the param name is "videoid", and in the test it is "videoId". Notice the case of 'i' in Id

Comment: Whats the output in the logfiles? You should have a stacktrace there with more explanations.

Comment: videoid != videoId.
Another thing is how you're mocking Manager. You cannot mock static methods (I assume you use Mockito). If it's just typo (manager is an instance) you should move when(...)... before calling mockMvc because you'll probably get null as response.

Comment: yes  i got response null because i am not set the value of response message. and i use the mockito ,and i have InjectMocks my controller in mock my manager. if you have better idea then please suggest me. THANKS.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP 400 Stands for **Bad Request**, which as per the [specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) should be returned when:

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.

Since in your controller you have defined: 
`@RequestParam(value = "videoid", required = true) String videoId)` and in your test you are passing videoId, spring is not able to match the videoid which is a required parameter and thus raises `400` error.

Please note, that the parameter in your request must match what you have defined as `value` in the `RequestParam` and not the name of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The one way to solve is to add(mvc:annotation-driven):

in your xml file where you have mentioned all the spring configuration.

When you execute the test case, the logs said that the given url pattern it wont find. Even the logs said it not found controller.

Might be this will help to someone.